# Phoenix New Install Cannot Compile :fs Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, elixir, phoenix-framework

Fresh install of Elixir, Erlang, Phoenix, etc. on Windows 10. I have installed Hex and rebar multiple times. No matter how many 'fixes' on read on various gits or other how-to pages, I cannot get `mix phoenix.server` to run. Same error everytime.

`mix phoenix.server
The system cannot find the path specified.
==> fs (compile)
** (Mix) Could not compile dependency :fs, "escript.exe "c:/Users/shawn.karber/.mix/rebar" compile skip_deps=true deps_dir="e:/sandbox/phoenix/test/test/_build/dev/lib"" command failed. You can recompile this dependency with "mix deps.compile fs", update it with "mix deps.update fs" or clean it with "mix deps.clean fs"`

I've refetched, updated, recompile, cleaned, reinstalled over and over and I cannot get the server to start. Anyone have any experience with this or have any idea how to fix it?

`node 6.9.1
erlang 19.0
elixir 1.4.1
rebar and rebar 3 both installed
all paths are in my PATH`

```
defmodule Test.Mixfile do
  use Mix.Project

  def project do
    [app: :test,
     version: "0.0.1",
     elixir: "~> 1.2",
     elixirc_paths: elixirc_paths(Mix.env),
     compilers: [:phoenix, :gettext] ++ Mix.compilers,
     build_embedded: Mix.env == :prod,
     start_permanent: Mix.env == :prod,
     aliases: aliases(),
     deps: deps()]
  end

  # Configuration for the OTP application.
  #
  # Type `mix help compile.app` for more information.
  def application do
    [mod: {Test, []},
     applications: [:phoenix, :phoenix_pubsub, :phoenix_html, :cowboy, :logger, :gettext,
                    :phoenix_ecto, :postgrex]]
  end

  # Specifies which paths to compile per environment.
  defp elixirc_paths(:test), do: ["lib", "web", "test/support"]
  defp elixirc_paths(_),     do: ["lib", "web"]

  # Specifies your project dependencies.
  #
  # Type `mix help deps` for examples and options.
  defp deps do
    [{:phoenix, "~> 1.2.1"},
     {:phoenix_pubsub, "~> 1.0"},
     {:phoenix_ecto, "~> 3.0"},
     {:postgrex, ">= 0.0.0"},
     {:phoenix_html, "~> 2.6"},
     {:phoenix_live_reload, "~> 1.0", only: :dev},
     {:gettext, "~> 0.11"},
     {:cowboy, "~> 1.0"}]
  end

  # Aliases are shortcuts or tasks specific to the current project.
  # For example, to create, migrate and run the seeds file at once:
  #
  #     $ mix ecto.setup
  #
  # See the documentation for `Mix` for more info on aliases.
  defp aliases do
    ["ecto.setup": ["ecto.create", "ecto.migrate", "run priv/repo/seeds.exs"],
     "ecto.reset": ["ecto.drop", "ecto.setup"],
     "test": ["ecto.create --quiet", "ecto.migrate", "test"]]
  end
end
```

Comment: I had some different issues with rebar and comeonin it turned out that I have to install VC++ and run `mix deps.get` via cmd after following this article - https://github.com/riverrun/comeonin/issues/75. Maybe it will help you.

Comment: Post your mix.exs file.

Comment: @Onorio Catenacci Added my mix.exs as requested.

Comment: I tend to agree with @PatNowak on this but it'd be helpful if you posted the output of your `mix deps.compile fs` command

Comment: I did fresh installation on Windows 10 for the latest Phoenix, Live Dashboard and Elixir. Just in case you want to see how to step and ensure everything works : https://www.yodiw.com/phoenix-elixir-installation-in-windows-10/